Spring Data MongoDB 3.4.6 will work with MongoDB 6.0, excluding the new features introduced in v6.0?
I am planning to update the MongoDB server from v5.0 to v6.0.
Current Setup:
Driver: 4.6.1
Spring Data MongoDB: 3.4.6
I am reviewing whether it is necessary to update the above libraries. Ideally, I would like to continue using the existing libraries. I have confirmed that Driver 4.6.1 does support MongoDB 6.0, though it does not support the new features introduced in v6.0 (cf. https://www.mongodb.com/ko-kr/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/compatibility/).
However, the Spring Data MongoDB compatibility table only provides information on versions that support all features of the server, so I cannot determine whether a library update is mandatory (cf. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/reference/preface.html).
To summarize, I would like to know if Spring Data MongoDB 3.4.6 will work with MongoDB 6.0, excluding the new features introduced in v6.0. I confirmed the official reference but can't find what i want to know.

Why don't you just try it out and build a proof of concept?

The compatibility table you linked to says "You can use newer server versions unless your application uses functionality that is affected by changes in the MongoDB server." You can read more about Upgrade Procedures here. Specifically, "To upgrade to MongoDB 6.0 from a 5.0 deployment, the 5.0 deployment must have featureCompatibilityVersion set to 5.0." Also see Compatibility Changes in MongoDB 6.0 and "Removed Operators".
